# How do I take a process dump?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, dump

Task manager has an option to "create dump file"
I need to create a program that does the same, either in C++, C#, or Python.
I have tried all 3 but none of them work like task manager does. for example I managed to create a mini dump using C++ but it only makes a 300 kb file, when the task manager dump is around 200mb

I tried making a program that does it using C++, C#, Python, none of them work correctly.

Here is a versio I made in C++

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 // Function to create a minidump of the specified process ID
void CreateMinidump(DWORD processId)
{
HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processId);
if (processHandle == NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to open process. Error code: %u\n", GetLastError());
    return;
}

// Generate a unique file name for the minidump
char dumpFileName[MAX_PATH];
sprintf_s(dumpFileName, sizeof(dumpFileName), "Minidump_%u.dmp", processId);

// Create the minidump file
HANDLE dumpFile = CreateFileA(dumpFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (dumpFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    printf("Failed to create minidump file. Error code: %u\n", GetLastError());
    CloseHandle(processHandle);
    return;
}

// Write the minidump
MINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION exceptionInfo;
exceptionInfo.ThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
exceptionInfo.ExceptionPointers = NULL;
exceptionInfo.ClientPointers = FALSE;

BOOL success = MiniDumpWriteDump(processHandle, processId, dumpFile, MiniDumpNormal, &exceptionInfo, NULL, NULL);
if (!success)
{
    printf("Failed to write minidump. Error code: %u\n", GetLastError());
}
else
{
    printf("Minidump created successfully: %s\n", dumpFileName);
}

// Cleanup
CloseHandle(dumpFile);
CloseHandle(processHandle);
}

int main()
{
// Get the process ID of the target process
DWORD targetProcessId = 13940;

// Create the minidump
CreateMinidump(targetProcessId);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: when you need help with code you wrote you need to show the code. Please create a [mcve], and remove all but the one language tag your code is in

Comment: will do that, sorry, kinda new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Try changing `MiniDumpNormal` to `MiniDumpWithFullMemory`. `Normal` is a very small one. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/minidumpapiset/ne-minidumpapiset-minidump_type) for more info